# Why when I generate a model with sequelize has a different structure than others that includes a class instead of a const?

Tags: node.js, express, model, sequelize.js

I'm new with sequelize and I've seen many tutorials on how to create models with sequelize, but when I did, this is the structure that created it.

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class User extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
    }
  };
  Users.init({
    nickname: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Users',
  });
  return User;
};
```

But the other structure that I see is "most popular" is this.

```
'use strict';

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    nickname: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING
  },{
    underscored: true
  });
  return User;
};
```

How can I generate a model with the second structure using "sequelize model:generate" in console?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the official [documentation](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-basics.html#model-definition) both methods to define a model are equal to each other. `define` is more popular because it's an older approach then `classes` and that's all. I recommend to use a newer one because I suppose it will have a longer life cycle and support.